intermediate value theorem $(\exists \alpha \in [a,b])$ such that $f(\alpha)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(x_k)$, want a shorter approach
Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$, and let {$x_1,x_1,\dots,x_n$} be points in $[a,b]$. Show that:
$$(\exists \alpha \in [a,b])\quad \text{such that}\quad f(\alpha)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(x_k)$$
Here's what i did, but i'm seeking a different approach, a short one perhaps:
Define the function
$$h(x) = n f(x) - \sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k)$$
Let$$ F = \{ f(x_1), f(x_2), \dots, f(x_n) \}$$
Assume: $f(x_i) = \min(F)  \text{ for some }  i \in \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$
This implies:
$$   f(x_k) \geq f(x_i) \quad \forall k \in \{1, 2, \dots, n\}.
$$
Consequently,
$$   \sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k) \geq n f(x_i).
$$
Therefore,
$$   h(x_i) \leq 0.
 $$
Assume: $f(x_j)=\min(F)$ for some $j \in \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$
This implies:$$f(x_k) \leq f(x_j) \quad \forall k \in \{1, 2, \dots, n\}.$$
Consequently,
$$\sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k) \leq n f(x_j).$$
Therefore,
$$h(x_j) \geq 0.$$
Applying the IVT
Since  $h(x_i) \leq 0$ and $h(x_j) \geq 0$, by the Intermediate Value Theorem, there exists some $\alpha \in [x_i, x_j]$ or $\alpha \in [x_j, x_i]$ such that:
$$h(\alpha) = 0.$$
Conclusion:
Since $[x_i, x_j] \subset [a, b]$ and $[x_j, x_i] \subset [a, b]$, it follows that:
$$\exists \alpha \in [a, b] \quad \text{such that} \quad h(\alpha) = 0.$$

Your proof is fine.  To shorten it, you could probably get away with "and similarly, $h(x_j) \geq 0$" since the proof is the same but with inequalities reversed. Or you could just say that $f(x_i) \leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(x_k) \leq  f(x_j)$, where $f(x_i)$ and $f(x_j)$ are the min and max resepctively, since the average of a set of values is always between the min and max (you can prove this if it's not "known") and apply the usual IVT to $f$ directly instead of to $h$.

Compare: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3378906/42969
